# How to program ArcGIS Pro 'vary symbology size by field' in arcpy

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

Is there a way to code in arcpy **Vary symbology by attribute** and the **Size** option.  I have a field in a point file that has values for the size, which can be done manually in the Symbology tab, but I would like to do this in a script : [ArcGIS Pro Symbology Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnG6P.png)

I couldn't find any online documentation or examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches you can use. The simplest would be to author the layer the way you prefer (that is to set symbology manually in ArcGIS Pro), save it to disk once and then load it whenever necessary:

```
#Save authored layer from active map
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m=aprx.activeMap
lyr = m.listLayers("YourLayer")[0] #your layer that already has proper symbology set
lyr.saveACopy("YourPath")

#Load authored layer
new_lyr = arcpy.mp.LayerFile("YourPath")
m.addLayer(new_lyr)
aprx.save()
#do necessary changes (e.g. change data path)
```

In most cases such approach should be enough. However, if your case is more complicated then you can use CIM model (Layer.Symbology doesn't support *Vary symbology by attribute*)
Here's documentation and some examples: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm

It will be helpful to use your saved layer file (which in fact is a JSON file) to learn the necessary structure (look for *render*)